# In Jest testing, how to set assert that expected array should be the same with ordering?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to compare arrays in Jest testing such that test passes only if arrays are completely the same (same elements, same order, same length).
Is there `expect()` function to do this without me writing the custom logic that compares each element?

Here is an example of what I want:

```
// expect these should be false
array1 = [1,2,3];
array2 = [3,2,1];
```

and:

```
// expect these should be true
array1 = [1,2,3];
array2 = [1,2,3];
```

Note I also need this when elements are objects and they are compared recursively (deep compare).

Comment: If the values of the arrays are only numbers/strings how about comparing ```JSON.stringify(array1)===JSON.stringify(array2)```

Comment: [`.toEqual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#toequalvalue)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe `toEqual` is absolutely correct, would you like to do the honors of creating an answer?